# Insert record for each user with role editor

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I need to insert a row for each user of role editor using mysql. I can insert rows but need to check the user role as im using a custom table separate from wp users.

```
Insert into assist trans (values) where (wp user role = editor)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making the assumption that you want a relation between assist and user.  So you want to use a subquery:

insert into assist (userid, something) 
select id, "somevalue" from users where role = "editor"

so first get a select statement that gives you the values you want to enter into assist and then make that the subquery that presents the values to the insert command.

Comment: The assist table is blank. I need to get user ids from wp users and give each an entry of '100' in the assist table 'amount' column. Assist table has columns 'amount' and 'user _id'.

Comment: insert into assist (user_id, amount) select users.id, "100" from users where role = "editor"

Comment: Please mark this answered if it works for you.  I need the rep points

Comment: it didn't work but you sent me in the right direction and therefor i will mark as correct. For those who need to use the query it is as follow: insert into `assist_trans` (user_id, amount) select `wp_usermeta`.user_id, 100 from `wp_usermeta` where meta_value = "member"  ... the change was that WordPress roles are stored in wp_usermeta table.